# For deterministic wallets, which key is better to give out?

Tags: address, electrum, deterministic-wallets

I am just finding out about deterministic wallets. I have read [here](https://bitcoinmagazine.com/articles/deterministic-wallets-advantages-flaw-1385450276/) that it is possible to derive the private key if one happens to have given out both master public key AND a child private key.

So if we want to give someone a key to send funds to, is there a better one to give out? Or can it be any, as long as we don't give out the other one?

Answer (score 2):

You give out a single address, as with a normal wallet. The master private key and master public key are both for use locally and should never be shared with any party, especially not the former.